# Customize VideoJS with Ionic icons in NextJS

Tags: css, next.js, video.js, ionicons

I'm building a website to serve videos and I am looking for a proper way to customize **VideoJS** player using **Ionic icons set** but since I use `<ion-icon/>` tag to add an icon to a page, the only way to achieve this was to specify each used icon *unicode* in a custom CSS.

What would be a better and cleaner way to make use of Ionicons with VideoJS ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this could be to  pick your icons from the `svg` folder  > https://github.com/ionic-team/ionicons/tree/main/src/svg

And then insert the icon in the videojs control bar via a [skin customization](https://player.support.brightcove.com/styling/customizing-player-appearance.html)